# Rationale behind the new Stack Snippets feature

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

I like the fact that the team is trying to improve the Stack Overflow editor. There is scope for it.

I am trying to understand the recently enhanced "Stack Snippets" feature. Seems like it allows users to run the code on the Stack Overflow site. Why would users look to run/test code on this site ? I would imagine they would have already done that in their IDE's and their dev environments.

Currently I only see support for running UI/Web/Browser related languages. Will this feature be enhanced to support other languages in the future ?

Comment: Stack snippets don't run server-side. They run client-side, in a sandbox.

Comment: thanks , have updated my question to reflect this !!

Comment: As soon as your browser can compile and run a C++ program.  6 to 8 decades.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, there are tools to compile C++ programs to JavaScript, and there are C++ compilers written in C++, so...

Answer (score 7):

The *questioner* certainly should have tested the code in their dev environment, but as an *answerer* it provides an easy way to test/see the behavior being described, without having to set up a new environment for the code.

It also helps remove JSFiddle links, which were in many cases being used for the code itself. Even when used correctly, you had to visit a different site. Now you can run the code without leaving the question.

As far as desktop languages go, no indication has been made that its coming, though I for one would love to see an IDEOne or .NETFiddle clone come to SO!

Comment: Better a coliru clone than an IDEOne clone. The latter one does not allow custom options, and deletes too much linked code.

Comment: @Deduplicator Bah, no C#. But you C++ folks can have that one :)